# How to compute p(w) in Machine Learning In Action 4.5.2

Tags: machine-learning, conditional-probability, naive-bayes

Machine Learning In Action 4.5.2 is about "Training: calculating probabilities from word vectors" and the target is to write code to compute

p(ci|w) = p(w|ci) * p(ci) / p(w)

The author talks about how to compute p(w|ci) and p(ci) here:

> We can calculate p(ci) by adding up how many times we see class i (abusive posts or non-abusive posts) and the dividing by the total number of posts.
>
> How can we get p(w|ci)? This is where our naive assumption comes in. ... says we can calculate this probability as p(w0|ci) * p(w1|ci) * p(w2|ci) * ... * p(wn|ci).

But he does not cover p(w), and I cannot find out how p(w) is calculated in his code as below:

```
def trainNB0(trainMatrix,trainCategory):
    numTrainDocs = len(trainMatrix)
    numWords = len(trainMatrix[0])
    pAbusive = sum(trainCategory)/float(numTrainDocs)
    p0Num = ones(numWords); p1Num = ones(numWords)
    p0Denom = 2.0; p1Denom = 2.0
    for i in range(numTrainDocs):
        if trainCategory[i] == 1:
            p1Num += trainMatrix[i]
            p1Denom += sum(trainMatrix[i])
        else:
            p0Num += trainMatrix[i]
            p0Denom += sum(trainMatrix[i])
    p1Vect = log(p1Num/p1Denom)
    p0Vect = log(p0Num/p0Denom)
    return p0Vect,p1Vect,pAbusive

def classifyNB(vec2Classify, p0Vec, p1Vec, pClass1):
    p1 = sum(vec2Classify * p1Vec) + log(pClass1)    #element-wise mult
    p0 = sum(vec2Classify * p0Vec) + log(1.0 - pClass1)
    if p1 > p0:
        return 1
    else: 
        return 0

def testingNB():
    listOPosts,listClasses = loadDataSet()
    myVocabList = createVocabList(listOPosts)
    trainMat=[]
    for postinDoc in listOPosts:
        trainMat.append(setOfWords2Vec(myVocabList, postinDoc))
    p0V,p1V,pAb = trainNB0(array(trainMat),array(listClasses))
    testEntry = ['love', 'my', 'dalmation']
    thisDoc = array(setOfWords2Vec(myVocabList, testEntry))
    print testEntry,'classified as: ',classifyNB(thisDoc,p0V,p1V,pAb)
    testEntry = ['stupid', 'garbage']
    thisDoc = array(setOfWords2Vec(myVocabList, testEntry))
    print testEntry,'classified as: ',classifyNB(thisDoc,p0V,p1V,pAb)
```

Could any one point out the line in the code above that does the trick of computing p(w) and explain how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no line in the code that computes $p(w)$, because it is not needed in this context. This implementation of the Naïve Bayes classifier labels a word $w$ as belonging to class 1 if $p(c_1|w) > p(c_0|w)$. By Bayes' rule, this condition is equivalent to
$$
\frac{p(w|c_1) p(c_1)}{p(w)} > \frac{p(w|c_0) p(c_0)}{p(w)}.
$$
Canceling $p(w)$ from both sides gives
$$
p(w|c_1) p(c_1) > p(w|c_0) p(c_0).
$$
So we never need $p(w)$ as long as we are strictly interested in classifying. If you wanted to report the actual values of the posterior probabilities, you would need to normalize by $p(w)$.

Comment: I got your point, thanks. Then how do I normalize by p(w) if I want to get the actual values of the probabilities?

Comment: For a particular word $w$, you can estimate $p(w)$ by dividing the number of occurrences of $w$ by the total number of words in your corpus.